# Django Celery Beat not sending tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

Triyng to figure uot why my scheduled tasks won't run.
Celery is working fine.

Celery and celery beat started via systemd

### Celery service

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=awert
Group=awert
WorkingDirectory=/home/awert/checker_f/
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/awert/checker_f/checker_e/bin/celery multi start w1 -A checker_p -l info --logfile=/home/awert/celery/sworker.log --pidfile=/home/awert/celery/worker.pid --time-limit=21600 -E -S django'

ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/home/awert/checker_f/checker_e/bin/celery multi stopwait w1 --pidfile=/home/awert/celery/worker.pid'

ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '/home/awert/checker_f/checker_e/bin/celery multi restart w1 -A checker_p -l info --pidfile=/home/awert/celery/worker.pid --logfile=/home/awert/celery/sworker.log --time-limit=21600 -E -S django'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Celerybeat service

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery beat
PartOf=celery.service

[Service]
User=awert
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/awert/checker_f/checker_e/bin/celery beat -A checker_p -l debug --pidfile=/home/awert/celery/beat.pid --logfile=/home/awert/celery/beat.log --workdir=/home/awert/checker_f/'
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As far as I can tell from logs celebeat acknowledges of scheduled tasks:

```
[2017-08-24 12:31:42,242: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2017-08-24 12:31:42,243: DEBUG/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: initial read
[2017-08-24 12:31:42,243: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2017-08-24 12:31:42,272: DEBUG/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: Fetching database schedule
[2017-08-24 12:31:42,286: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
<ModelEntry: Sanity sanity_check(*[], **{}) <crontab: */2 * * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>>
<ModelEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup(*[], **{}) <crontab: 0 4 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>>
[2017-08-24 12:31:42,326: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 seconds
[2017-08-24 12:31:42,331: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
[2017-08-24 12:31:47,337: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2017-08-24 12:31:47,337: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2017-08-24 12:31:47,342: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
```

After that only

```
[2017-08-24 12:34:42,624: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
[2017-08-24 12:34:47,630: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2017-08-24 12:34:47,631: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
```

But sanity_check task never runs.
celerybeat.service is different from what documentation shows, but is the one that worked for me.

Any advice?

UPD: for some reason task was fired 3 times with interval of 2 hours and 32 minutes while crontab is set */2 * * *

Comment: Finaly figured out the problem: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4184